# loop through a list without array in shell

Tags: shell-script, busybox

I'm trying to write a short shell script to loop through a list (given by a certain command I run) line by line and push values to CSV file

a
list for  example:

```
aaa   bbb   ccc   ddd   eee   fff
jjj   kkk   lll   mmm   nnn   ooo
uuu   vvv   www   xxx   yyy   zzz
```

Need to loop through this and for each line take 1st,4rd and 6th fields into variables so I can do some manipulation on them.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
CSVfile="/tmp/`hostname`.csv"
filter=$( command )
touch $CSVfile
#
for i in $filter
do 

    first=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$1'})
    fourth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$4'})
    sixth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$6'})
    cmd=$( cat /home/app/$first/$fourth/out | grep value | awk -F: {'print$2'})
    echo `date +%d%m%Y,%H%M%S`,"$sixth","$cmd" >> $CSVfile

done
```

the problem here is the for loop goes field by field and not line by line.
need each line goes into $i so I can parse it with "awk"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved by using while loop with IFS which gets filter variable as input.

Could not find a why to push command into while loop w/o store it in variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
CSVfile="/tmp/`hostname`.csv"
filter=$( command )
touch $CSVfile
#
while IFS= read -r line
do
    first=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$1'})
    fourth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$4'})
    sixth=$( printf "$i" | awk {'print$6'})
    cmd=$( cat /home/app/$first/$fourth/out | grep value | awk -F: {'print$2'})
    echo `date +%d%m%Y,%H%M%S`,"$sixth","$cmd" >> $CSVfile

done < $filter
```